# How do I enable/disable chunked Transfer encoding for a multi part POST that includes a file part using the OkHttp client?

Tags: okhttp

I am looking to use the OkHttp client to perform a multi part POST that has a potentially large file part. How do I enable chunked transfer encoding for files above a certain size?

Comment: Why do you want this? OkHttp will use fixed length encoding if it knows the file size, chunked encoding otherwise.

Comment: AFAIK fixed encoding will load the whole file into memory which will cause problems if the files are several hundred megabytes in size

Comment: OkHttp doesn’t load the entire request it all into memory when it uses fixed-length encoding.

Comment: Thank you I didn't realise, that's good to know and solves my client issue. However I may need to force chunked for the server which is not under my control to accept the file without out of memory errors. So is it just a case of overriding the content length header?

Comment: Yep. Returning -1. But you should also get the server’s owners to fix their bug. Not supporting fixed-length encoding is a protocol violation.